# How do I interpret the results returned by getcifsacl?

Tags: samba, active-directory, acl, cifs

I'm reviewing permissions on a local directory provided by a remote Samba server. The server itself is Linux (Ubuntu 16.04). The local machine is Centos 7. When I run `getcifsacl` I get the data, for example, returned below. I've never seen SIDs like this, and they don't necessarily matchup with what is in `man setcifsacl.`

The Samba server security is ADS.

```
REVISION:0x1
CONTROL:0x9004
OWNER:S-1-5-21-107619651-339024737-1120166462-8298
GROUP:S-1-22-2-48
ACL:S-1-5-21-107619651-339024737-1120166462-3274:ALLOWED/OI|CI/FULL
ACL:S-1-5-21-107619651-339024737-1120166462-512:ALLOWED/OI|CI/FULL
ACL:S-1-5-21-107619651-339024737-1120166462-10452:ALLOWED/OI|CI/READ
ACL:S-1-22-1-10403:ALLOWED/OI|CI/FULL
ACL:S-1-22-1-10387:ALLOWED/OI|CI/READ
ACL:S-1-22-1-10369:ALLOWED/OI|CI/READ
ACL:S-1-22-1-10111:ALLOWED/OI|CI/READ
ACL:S-1-5-21-107619651-339024737-1120166462-1480:ALLOWED/OI|CI/READ
ACL:Everyone@WORLD AUTHORITY:ALLOWED/OI|CI/
ACL:S-1-5-21-107619651-339024737-1120166462-8298:ALLOWED/0x0/FULL
ACL:S-1-5-21-107619651-339024737-1120166462-10315:ALLOWED/0x0/READ
ACL:S-1-22-2-48:ALLOWED/0x0/FULL
ACL:S-1-22-1-10298:ALLOWED/0x0/READ
ACL:S-1-5-21-107619651-339024737-1120166462-4073:ALLOWED/0x0/READ
ACL:CREATOR OWNER@CREATOR AUTHORITY:ALLOWED/OI|CI|IO/FULL
ACL:CREATOR GROUP@CREATOR AUTHORITY:ALLOWED/OI|CI|IO/FULL
ACL:S-1-22-1-10298:ALLOWED/OI|CI|IO/FULL
ACL:S-1-5-21-107619651-339024737-1120166462-4073:ALLOWED/OI|CI|IO/FULL
```

What are the 4 groups of numbers? Ex: OWNER:S-1-5-21-**107619651-339024737-1120166462-8298**

I'm assuming it is a UID of some type, but to whom does it map and on what system? The Samba server or ADS?

For my use case specifically, the only thing is identifiable is '48' in GROUP, which is the GID of the Linux group that should be assigned.

The man pages describe a lot, but for anything it doesn't cover, can you provide a resource that can explain this output in more detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The long [SIDs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/manage/understand-security-identifiers) starting with `S-1-5-21-` are probably the *most regular* kind of SID and represent some kind of regular Windows NT account (user, computer, group) in some domain. In this SID type, the first 3 groups of numbers identify the specific domain (either an AD domain **or** an individual machine's "local accounts" domain) while the final group – the RID – identifies the specific account in that domain and is similar to an UID (or a GID) on Linux.

In your output, `S-1-5-21-107619651-339024737-1120166462` is most likely the "domain SID" of your Active Directory domain. The RID `512` always belongs to the "Domain Admins" group (it's in the "Well-known SIDs" table), while RIDs above 1000 are regular created accounts.

If the Linux system was actually domain-joined and had either Winbindd or SSSD set up correctly, I believe `getcifsacl` is supposed to automatically resolve all SIDs into names using winbindd's local API.

The SIDs starting with `S-1-22-`, on the other hand, directly represent *Unix* accounts (UIDs and GIDs have different prefixes). They're used by Samba in some situations, as well as (if I remember correctly) the NFS server feature within Windows Server. The last number is the UID (or GID) within the specific server that the file is on. For example, `S-1-22-1-10298` is UID 10298 (and I'm *guessing* the server uses a 1:1 mapping of domain RIDs to Unix UIDs, but that's not always the case) while `S-1-22-2-48` is GID 48.

Many other SIDs (not in your list) represent some other kind of entity, and you can find most of them in the ["Well-known SIDs" table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/manage/understand-security-identifiers).

Comment: Thank you, that's extremely helpful. Just to clarify, in the OWNER row, for example, the `8298` is an RID and corresponds to a specific NT account in that domain. I'm assuming that and others like 3274, 4073 are specific to my enterprise since they were not in the 'well-known' tables, and I should be able to cross reference them in AD? And if I'm understanding correctly, if Winbind or SSSD were working correctly, I'd see something more readable?

Comment: Yes, RIDs above 1000 are assigned to manually created AD accounts, while RIDs below 1000 belong to standard entries pre-created during domain setup. You can search AD via LDAP for the `(objectSid=...)` or use `wbinfo` if winbindd is set up at all. (Assuming the account hasn't been deleted, of course...) Integration of getcifsacl with winbindd might be shipped as a separate library package that you need to install either a winbindd version or an sssd version of.